# PDBs: What is the C:\Windows\Symbols\dll directory?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, debug-symbols, pdb-files

I know about debugging symbols (PDBs), the [MS Symbol Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503/en-us) and the caching of symbols.

What I do not get is which symbols (by whom) go into the `C:\Windows\Symbols\dll` directory. It doesn't seem `C:\Windows\Symbols\dll` has anything to do with MSSS caching.

Example, my version of this directory contains:

```
C:\Windows\Symbols\dll>dir

21.02.2013  16:47    <DIR>          .
21.02.2013  16:47    <DIR>          ..
18.02.2011  16:18         3.854.336 atl100.i386.pdb
18.02.2011  18:23        25.300.992 mfc100.i386.pdb
18.02.2011  18:22        28.938.240 mfc100d.i386.pdb
18.02.2011  18:23        25.473.024 mfc100u.i386.pdb
18.02.2011  18:23        29.241.344 mfc100ud.i386.pdb
18.02.2011  18:26         4.386.816 mfcm100.i386.pdb
18.02.2011  18:26         4.452.352 mfcm100d.i386.pdb
18.02.2011  18:26         4.403.200 mfcm100u.i386.pdb
18.02.2011  18:26         4.468.736 mfcm100ud.i386.pdb
18.02.2011  18:05            13.824 Microsoft.Workflow.ExpressionEvaluation.pdb
18.02.2011  16:18         3.755.008 msvcp100.i386.pdb
18.02.2011  16:18         4.377.600 msvcp100d.i386.pdb
18.02.2011  16:17         8.875.008 msvcr100.i386.pdb
18.02.2011  16:18         7.900.160 msvcr100d.i386.pdb
18.02.2011  18:26         1.699.840 vcomp100.i386.pdb
18.02.2011  18:26         1.798.144 vcomp100d.i386.pdb
```

But no other files, although this machine has both VS2005 and VS2010 installed. I always thought the files get put there by VS, but since the `...80...` versions are missing (which I have on other machines), it seems VS2005 didn't put them there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are pdbs that help you step through the MFC code. This is being put in here by VS and more specifically the VC++ installation which would be a part of your VS install.

Comment: Hmm ... OK, so my VS2005 installation would appear broken ... may be, I had tried a few things with servicepacks / hotfixes recently and then uninstalled these ... may be that the MS uninstaller messed something up wrt. these files.

Comment: Actually I am not very familiar with VS2005. It just may be that this wasn't being dropped as a part of VS2005. I have seen that this is being placed in the same directory in VS2010 and VS2012 installs for sure.